# Dynamically Select Tables Sets using Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, dynamic

I'm trying to write a function that will Dynamically select Entities Table Data by passing in a Type.  Preferable one that kept all of the data in SQL until I call an execute.  So I can Chain addition queries on to it before execution.

Right now I'm trying to do this by using Create Query and Extending my entities object

```
public ObjectQuery<T> GetEntityData<T>()
        where T : class
{
    ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext; 
    string TableName = objectContext.GetCurrentTableName<T>();
    return objectContext.CreateQuery<T>("select * from " + TableName);
}

public static class ContextExtensions
{

    public static string GetCurrentTableName<T>(this ObjectContext context) where T : class
    {
        string sql = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().ToTraceString();
        Regex regex = new Regex("FROM (?<table>.*) AS");
        Match match = regex.Match(sql);

        string table = match.Groups["table"].Value;
        return table;
    }
}
```

Where I execute this code though, I keep gettting an error "The query syntax is not valid. Near term '*', line 3, column 9."  That May be because Create query needs EntitySql Syntax instead of T-SQL, would anyone know what I need to do to make this return the right data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer was already in there from the contextExtensions

```
public IQueryable<T> GetEntityData<T>()
    where T : class
{
    ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;


    return (objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>() as IQueryable<T>).Where("ID > 19000");
}
```